# How to create a ready to publish to npm angular 2 library

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I will be very specific and will divide my question into points.

**1. What I want to achieve in overall:**

Creating a ready to be published to npm angular 2 boilerplate library (latest version)

**2. What is not working:**

Both tutorials beneath, cited at stackoverflow earlier are not working properly in many aspects or are outdated or just not very clear. Also in the Internet there is more confusion than information about how to prepare a valid and working angular 2 library.

http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/

https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435#.c3yuzcrgj

**3. What I want to achieve in specific:**

I would like to know the steps and summarize here what is essential for
    creating the library in the latest angular 2 version from scratch. With code
    examples. May it serve all stackoverflowers for the future as a
    working boilerplate.

What I propose is to write down a shortest possible list what needs to be done in points, with code examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you want to create a component and publish it as a library.

### 1. Create the component

You need to create your `foo.component.ts` file and its html template. You'll prefer inline css (in `styles` attribute of `@Component`).

**!!! Don't forget to set `moduleId: module.id` in `@Component` to link the template to your component using a relative path !!!**

### 2. Compile the code (once you tested it, the testing part is implicit)

You need to compile your component using `tsc` and a `tsconfig` which should look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

### 3. Publish to npm

First of all, create your .npmignore file, here is an example:

```
.idea

*.ts
!*.d.ts

/typings.json
/typings/
/node_modules/
/.gitignore
/.npmignore
/.travis.yml

/test
/karma.conf.js
/karma-test-shim.js

/rollup.config.js
/rollup-min.config.js

/systemjs.config.js

/tsconfig.json
/tsconfig-build.json
```

If you're not using a JetBrains IDE, remove `.idea` entry.

then set your publish configuration in `package.json`:

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
}
```

Once everything is ready, you can `npm publish`.

### Example

A good example of an external library for `angular2` can be found here: 
https://github.com/noemi-salaun/ng2-logger/

Or here for a more up-to-date one, including webpack compatibility:
https://github.com/kaiu-lab/serializer

It's not a component, but the whole publish config, bundling and testing logic is well done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise answer :). I will be testing it shortly and will give feedback :).

Comment: Are you the creator of the logger ? I like the idea but just fyi you can use error, warn, etc with the console as well, and you can remove console expression when you build.

Comment: no I'm not, it's one of my friends. But yes we know that you can remove console etc, the main reason why we wanted to have this logger is to be able to connect a different logger logic (eg. log to an api for monitoring purposes) easily.