# Exportable Angular "ng-cli" Modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an architecture that consists of multiple Angular applications created with `ng-cli`:

```
FrontendLibs
  @company/
    core/
      src/
      package.json
      index.ts
  main-app/
    src/
    package.json
```

In this example my two `ng-cli`applications are `Core` and `Home`.

I want to export a module from `Core`, say `SharedLibraryModule`, so that `Home` can use it. I'm doing so in the form of a local NPM package:

```
// package.json in main-app
{
    "@company/core": "file:./@company/core/"
}
```

The `@company/core` module contains an `index.ts` file that exports the module in question:

```
// index.ts in @company/core
export { SharedLibraryModule } from './src/app/shared-library/shared-library.module';
```

However, when I reference the SharedLibraryModule within my `main-app` and run an `ng-serve`, I get the following error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

Here's the `app.module.ts` for `main-app`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { SharedLibraryModule } from '@company/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedLibraryModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I export a module via a local npm package (**Or NPM Link**) so I can use it in other Angular applications (created through `ng-cli`)?

Things I've tried:

- Removing the scoped package using `core/` on its own, rather than
  `@company/core`
- Building `@company/core` with AOT -- this required
  setting up a lot of configuration to generate relevant `.js` files
  and metadata

Additionally, the above does work *after* I make an insignificant change and save somewhere in the source to re-compile. It's only on the initial compilation that this fails. However, it will fail identically every time that the `ng serve` command is called.

---

**EDIT**

Here are the steps that I needed in order to get this to work:

1. Build the app for production: `ng build --env=prod`
2. Generate a `.tgz` file for the app: `npm pack`
3. Reference `.tgz` file directly from the consumer within the `package.json`: `"@company/core": "file:../company-core-0.0.0.tgz"`
4. Observe successful `ng serve` builds

Note:

- No need to include a custom `tsconfig-build.json` file, or a `.npmignore` file
- Don't need to use `moduleId: module.id` within component decorators
- `npm link` will not work. Use `npm pack` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-module-template). I used this as a template to build a reusable local Angular npm library that I shared between my mobile ionic app and my web app. I think the key thing here is that there is an issue currently with npm link, use [npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) instead if you can't publish it to npm, and then reference the module like below in yor package.json file. Also remember to run the ngc script before npm pack.

```
 "my-core-module": "file:../core/my-core-module-1.0.0.tgz",
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even know that command existed. I'll mess around with it and see if that solves the issue. It's a little less ideal than link because you have to re-generate builds on changes.

Comment: @aiokos That's correct. I was hoping to go with link too, but it just wouldn't work with the webpack builds of the CLI.

Comment: I've added a few notes to the build process that you outlined within my post, but your answer was ultimately the right path. Thanks!

Comment: Hey also, do you happen to have a source for the `npm link` bug you mentioned? I'd like track when that gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To either link or use npm you need to create a build of the shared project. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40261896/2564847)  might help you.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll run through those steps and see if I can get it to work. It may be important to note that my example does work after the initial compilation -- meaning if I keep webpack running and make an insignificant change and save to trigger a re-compile, it will compile correctly. It's only on the initial compilation that the error is thrown. This makes me think it's not an issue with the build of the package.

Comment: I had the same problem. It kind a worked, but to go to production you really need to create a package.