# Angular2 module as npm module

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an Angular2 project. In it I have a DisplayModule which contains components/directives/pipes/services used to do display stuff.

What do I have to do to make this a npm module which I can them load in other projects.

So far I have:

1. Extracted the folder as in a separate git folder, which contains the `display.module.ts` file in which I import and export all the relevant things from within this folder.
2. Tried to find what to do with this folder so that I can import it. From my understanding the steps are as follows:

   a) do something to compile it into js files

   b) export those js files as a package

   c) publish those js files as a private npm package

   d) include this package with `npm install` in another project

As you have probably guessed I have no idea how to do all the points under 2.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a ready to publish to npm angular 2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261492/how-to-create-a-ready-to-publish-to-npm-angular-2-library)